# Using Aggregate to wire linq to put result in POCO

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, poco, aggregate

Using EF4 I am trying to come up with a smarter way of aggregating data from entities to Business objects, i.e. wiring the linq to deliver data directly to my BE, saving the step of subsequently copying from an IEnumerable after the linq. I have been trying to play around with something like the following, but cannot seem to get the syntax right. CustomerBE is a plain POCO.

```
        var customers = uow
               .GetAllCustomers()
               .Aggregate((list,obj) => new List<CustomerBE>()
               {
                  var beo = new CustomerBE { FirstName = obj.Firstname,
                                             Id = obj.Id
                                              ...
                                           };
                  list.Add(beo);
                  return list; 
               });
```

Comment: It's generally best to avoid causing side effects in LINQ queries (adding items to a list inside of an aggregate call).  It's contrary to it's design.  You should be returning the created objects based on the query, not modifying something inside of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just do this in a `Select` statement?  `Select` is intended to map from one type to another:

```
var customers = uow
           .GetAllCustomers()
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Select(c => new CustomerBE { FirstName = c.Firstname,
                                         Id = c.Id
                                          // ...
                                       }
                  )
           .ToList();
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, I guess I was lead down the wrong path by the name Aggregation, thinking I should be using that, since that is what I am trying to do, rather than Select.

Comment: @aggaton - Aggregate means "reduce" in map/reduce slang. It is responsible of producing a scalar value out of set (Sum, Count, Max etc.). Select is what you were looking for

Comment: @aggaton AZ is right - Aggregate is "reduce", and Select is "map" - you're trying to "map" from one type to another, which is exactly what select does...